# Unable to show AlertDialog on button click in a ListView

Tags: android, button, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

Everytime getting exception, whenever trying to show AlertDialog on button click of list view item, I am using below code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transport> {
    Context context;
    .......

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Transport> arrayList) {
        super(context, resource, arrayList);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        ..........
      }

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);

viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {                 

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Message")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();                                 

            }
        });
```

I don't know where i am doing `mistake` ? because i saw on many `SO` links, that we should have to use `context` in place of `getApplicationContext()` - even after that i am facing exception

**Log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.android.fields, PID: 920
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
at com.and.field.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:100)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the `line` where i am getting `exception`:

```
 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: where is your logcat? and where you initialized your `viewHolder.btnDelete` ?

Comment: post your logcat please..

Comment: Use `AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())` if you think problem is with context or getting `BadTokenException: Unable to add window` exception

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK bro i have tried with v.getContext() and getContext() but did not get any success ...

Comment: @Sun I'm having the save issue but unable to find any solution can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Dialogs needs Activity context. So first make sure that the context object which you passing to adapter is of `Activity` and then use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity) context);
```

Or either you can use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```

as ρяσѕρєя K suggested.

Answer (score 1):

By the way You can get the context without passing it in the constructor, as extended ArrayAdapter has its context. --> you can reach that with getContext().
But the problem is much deeper, as there are special cases where context is not null, but cannot be used for anything.. (I have the same kind of problem, just in rxJava environment).. So try to extract the whole AlertDialog.Builder part to a different class, with context initialisation somewhere else. A Short Example:

```
public class DialogManager {

    private static DialogManager instance = null;

    private Context context;

    public void initialize(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static DialogManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance=new DialogManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void showBasicErrorDialog(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.error))
                .setPositiveButton(getContext().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //TODO anything you want
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }   
                // TODO .setNegativeButton .. etc.

                }).create();

        dialog.show();

    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

And add this line into your Main Activity, or Application:

```
DialogManager.getInstance().initialize(this);
```

Then in your getView() function you can just call:

```
    // ...
    viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        DialogManager.getInstance().showBasicErrorDialog("Title","Message");
    }
});
```

And this way it is more general, you can use your dialog from other classes too. 
I'm not sure if it solves the problem, but is should..

Comment: thank you so much but what if i have to delete current list item ?

Comment: You can past that item too, like somehow this:showBasicDialog(Listitem item, message, title)

Comment: Sometimes getContext() works in ArrayAdapter, and then you dont need to extract the whole stuff..

Comment: sorry but this would not work for me, and i tried with v.getContext() and getContext() but did not get any success - always getting BadTokenException: Unable to add window exception

Comment: I post another answer, try that one, maybe :)

Comment: Why posting two answers for a sigle question?

Comment: I felt it is better because both can be good in some cases. but just for you I've deleted the 2nd.. Also you could tell the answer instead of a starting arguing with someone who is trying to help.

Comment: @PéterSzűcs So kind :D. First read the rule of stackoverflow. you need to post only one answer for a question. So do not argu for such nonsence work.